# Rotate all pages of PDF from command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, pdf

Is there any way to rotate PDF pages from the command line in in OS X?

Answer (score 2):

[Sejda's command line can help rotate PDF pages](http://www.sejda.org/).

```
./bin/sejda-console rotate --rotation 90 --files /tmp/file.pdf --output /tmp --pageSelection 4,12-14
```

Open source project, free, I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Not in homebrew. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`qpdf`](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html).  From the manual:

> --rotate=[+|-]angle[:page-range]
>
> Apply rotation to specified pages. The page-range portion of the option value has the same format as page ranges in Section 3.4, “Page
>   Selection Options”. If the page range is omitted, the rotation is
>   applied to all pages. The angle portion of the parameter may be either
>   90, 180, or 270. If preceded by + or -, the angle is added to or
>   subtracted from the specified pages' original rotations. Otherwise the
>   pages' rotations are set to the exact value. For example, the command
>   qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate=+90:2,4,6 --rotate=180:7-8 would rotate
>   pages 2, 4, and 6 90 degrees clockwise from their original rotation
>   and force the rotation of pages 7 through 9 to 180 degrees regardless
>   of their original rotation, and the command qpdf in.pdf out.pdf
>   --rotate=180 would rotate all pages by 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using `pdf90`, `pdf180` or `pdf270`, which are all part of `pdfjam` and is convenient if you already have `mactex`. Otherwise you can install it with homebrew cask, by `brew cask install mactex`. To rotate the PDF `document.pdf` 90 degrees anticlockwise, use:

```
pdf90 document.pdf
```

This will create a file `document-rotated90.pdf`. See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394065/command-line-how-do-you-rotate-a-pdf-file-90-degrees).

**UPDATE**

As of 3.02 the scripts are not part of [`pdfjam`](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam) any more, but  of the unsupported [`pdfjam-extras`](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam-extras/tree/master/bin). Use instead:

```
pdfjam --angle 90 --fitpaper true document.pdf
pdfjam --angle 180 document.pdf
pdfjam --angle 270 --fitpaper true document.pdf
```

Use the suffix option to alter the default suffix `-pdfjam`, such as `--suffix rotated270`.

Comment: Installing MacTeX to rotate a PDF may be an overkill...